How should I summarize a YouTube video of an integral that motivated my research paper without plagiarizing or being accused of plagiarism?
I conduct independent mathematics research in my spare time, and two years ago I stumbled upon a video evaluating an integral with relatively standard techniques (i.e. very straightforward and nonbiased). About 75% of the way through the video, the uploader's method produced an equation that intrigued me; I investigated it further, and it has now grown into a research paper that is already 17 pages long.
Since a part of the video played such a pivotal role in my research paper, I cited it in its introduction; however, I'm having trouble finding a proper balance between summarizing the video and building enough foundation for such a deep analysis. If I do the former, then I usually skip over everything except the aforementioned equation when the step beforehand is what motivated me to investigate deeper in the first place. However, if I do the latter, then I end up listing almost every step bar-for-bar and feel like I'm stepping over the uploader's toes by writing out most of the video's contents, depriving them of potential revenue if the stars align and I ever publish the paper.
The uploader doesn't claim copyright in the video, its description, or their channel page, but the video is not attributed with a Creative Commons license and I'm very wary of intellectual property in academia. What would be the best way to approach this?

Note that in most places, it is not necessary to “claim” copyright: the very act of producing something creates a copyright to it (barring a few exceptions e.g. around work-for-hire)—what you would need would be a clear statement relinquishing copyright. Absent that, it must be assumed that the creator retains copyright and reserves all rights. (Also, some jurisdictions make relinquishing copyright awkward and difficult, so even that isn’t always useful; see e.g. the “Creative Commons 0” license and its rationale for discussions of that.)

Frankly, I don't think you have any moral or academic obligation to protect a YouTuber's ad revenue here.

You're not going to decrease anyone's ad revenue by summarising their YouTube video in a paper. Nobody's going to read your paper and then later see the video pop up in their feed and think "oh, I remember reading about this video in a paper, I guess I don't need to click on it." On the other hand, if your paper is successful, a few people might seek out the video who might not have seen it otherwise.

I am very interested in evaluating integrals. I would be curious to see your preprint once it is available.

You don't need to summarize sources you cite, you need to credit them for what you use them for. If it's just an equation, you should note that. If you use it for more, you have to note that, too.
Copyright is moot here; academic ethics require you to cite whatever the license might be.

I do that with all of my other sources, I'm not sure what it is about an integral video that made me hesitate so much. Regardless, thank you for setting me straight.

Also: Owning copyright to a work is not dependent on registering, or giving notice of that copyright according to the Berne Convention.

+1 for the core answer — but just adding, to guard against overinterpretation, that it is also fine to sometimes summarise the cited sources, if that’s what the exposition of your own paper requires.  The key principle is cite clearly and generously — whether you’re just pointing to the work or also summarising/paraphrasing some material from it, you must make the extent of the relationship clear to the reader.

One concern is that the video might be taken down for any number of reasons. Would it be worth creating a summary that can be included as well anyway?

I would strongly consider including a complete derivation of the formula in your paper, so the academic record is complete: a YouTube video is not peer-reviewed and could become unavailable at any moment. By making your paper self-contained you ensure that it will remain readable even if the video becomes unavailable, and it ensures that all aspects of your results are peer-reviewed. Your paper should contain enough details of the video to be independently readable.
It's not a plagiarism issue if you properly attribute it.
It's probably not a copyright issue. Copyright covers the "creative work" that is the presentation of the formula in the video, but it doesn't cover the "idea" that is the formula itself. It's extremely unlikely that summarizing a line of mathematical reasoning from a YouTube video would violate copyright.
I do not think a 17 page math research paper has any chance of significantly affecting the revenue of a youtube video. It's probably more likely that you'll drive views to the video rather than detracting from it. Even then, most people would consider scientific progress more important than a YouTuber's revenue.

Copyright protects the "expression" of an idea, not the idea. The latter is protected by patents (if that's at all relevant, since mathematical derivations are not typically patentable). So summary of the video (the "expression" of the idea) does not violate the copyright if it is sufficiently differently expressed. Only citation is needed.

Even if copyright might have been at issue, most jurisdictions have a fair use/fair dealing exception that explicitly covers excerpts and summarization for the purposes of review and analysis, particularly in academic contexts.

I agree (and upvoted) but I'd argue that showing how the formula was derived is not always really necessary or relevant. For example, a paper about the Drake Equation would not typically need to explain basically anything about the Drake Equation beyond defining the terms, even if Drake's 1865 paper became somehow unavailable.
In a paper about, or building on, the derivation, it'd be necessary; otherwise, possibly unnecessary unless it's relevant to using the formula.

Note that plagiarism requires one to present another’s work as your own (or in rare instances self-plagiarise). Therefore to answer the question in the title, you avoid plagiarism by correctly attributing your source, e.g.
I am indebted to John Smith of the YouTube channel “Maths is awesome” for introducing me to this problem in his video “how to solve this cool integral”. The following paragraph contains a brief summary of the video…

I think that's perfectly fine if the video played an extremely pivotal role in asking/answering the question, but otherwise it might be over the top, especially in the main text (vs. acknowledgements). For a run-of-the-mill contribution, you could just cite it normally: "The integral can be solved using standard (Smith, 2023), which are briefly summarized here."

+1 one for an explicit statement how to handle the situation.
